# Using Conan (and SVN) as a dependence manager for Matlab projects

Tags: matlab, svn, conan

I'm looking into using **Conan.io** as a package/dependency manager for simple source-code projects in Matlab/Python.

We are a team of around 20 developers (of very different experience levels) with a single SVN server set up, including all our source code, and unfurtunately, also huge amounts data recordings (that rarely, but could, change). Various projects on the SVN server (checked out locally to different locations) require  common source code folders, and data files, across the server, and thus at the moment we have issues with multiple local checkouts of various folders, resulting in a disgusting mess and a lot of duplicate data on our PC's.

Therefore, I'm looking to see if Conan.io can do the trick for us, and it appears Conan should be able to do much more, given that it is intended for C/C++ projects. Can anyone give me a heads up on best-practice to use Conan for being able to check out projects/folders (i.e. conan packages) into a common folder, such that if:

**P1 requires D, and P2 requires D, then C will only be checked out once, into a local directory that is predictable (e.g. `/Users/XXX/.conan/YYY/`).**

We are open to omitting SVN and installing Conan on a server.

Comment: Yes, I think that conan might be able to do this. As you can see, it can be used for other languages too, like: http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/conan_as_other_languages_package_manager.html as the conan core  is quite generic with source-build-package methods. What do you mean by a "common folder"? Conan packages are installed in a common cache, to avoid rebuilding, and can be used from there. In the case of Matlab, we could code a generator that will add the paths. Then, also, package contents can be copied to a local project folder to be used from there (check the golang docs).

Comment: Also, this might be more a discussion than a SO Q&A, so feel free to send an email to info@conan.io or submit a github issue: https://github.com/conan-io/conan